# My dropdown from nav bar goes behind the slideshow. Could someone help me figure it out?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I already tried to mess up the position of each elements(gallery container, aka slideshow and navbar), but im not getting any result. Could you help me figure out what kind of property could i use to get a different result? Thanks alot in advance for whom help me.

[A screenshot of my dropdown navbar behind the slideshow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EylCh.jpg)

```js
//      FUNCAO RELOGIO
function time() {
    today=new Date();
    now=new Date();
    hours=today.getHours();
    minutes=today.getMinutes();
    seconds=today.getSeconds();
    if(hours < 10) {
        hours = "0" + hours;
    }    
    if(minutes < 10) {
        minutes = "0" + minutes;
    }
    if(seconds < 10) {
        seconds = "0" + seconds;
    }
    document.getElementById('tempoActual').innerHTML=now.getDate() + "/" + (now.getMonth()+1) + "/" + now.getFullYear()+"&nbsp;&nbsp;"+  hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
    setTimeout('time()',500);
}



//       FUNCAO TOOGLE
function toggle(ID){
    var element = document.getElementById(ID);
    if(element.style.display === "none"){
        element.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        element.style.display = "none";
    }
}


//      FUNCOES SLIDESHOW 

var slideIndex,slides,dots,captionText;
function initGallery(){
    slideIndex = 0;
    slides=document.getElementsByClassName("imageHolder");
    slides[slideIndex].style.opacity=1;

    captionText=document.querySelector(".captionTextHolder .captionText");
    captionText.innerText=slides[slideIndex].querySelector(".captionText").innerText;

    //disable nextPrevBtn if slide count is one
    if(slides.length<2){
        var nextPrevBtns=document.querySelector(".leftArrow,.rightArrow");
        nextPrevBtns.style.display="none";
        for (i = 0; i < nextPrevBtn.length; i++) {
            nextPrevBtn[i].style.display="none";
        }
    }   

    //add dots
    dots=[];
    var dotsContainer=document.getElementById("dotsContainer"),i;
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        var dot=document.createElement("span");
        dot.classList.add("dots");
        dotsContainer.append(dot);
        dot.setAttribute("onclick","moveSlide("+i+")");
        dots.push(dot);
    }
    dots[slideIndex].classList.add("active");
}

initGallery();
function plusSlides(n) {
    moveSlide(slideIndex+n);
}
function moveSlide(n){
    var i;
    var current,next;
    var moveSlideAnimClass={
          forCurrent:"",
          forNext:""
    };
    var slideTextAnimClass;
    if(n>slideIndex) {
        if(n >= slides.length){n=0;}
        moveSlideAnimClass.forCurrent="moveLeftCurrentSlide";
        moveSlideAnimClass.forNext="moveLeftNextSlide";
        slideTextAnimClass="slideTextFromTop";
    }else if(n<slideIndex){
        if(n<0){n=slides.length-1;}
        moveSlideAnimClass.forCurrent="moveRightCurrentSlide";
        moveSlideAnimClass.forNext="moveRightPrevSlide";
        slideTextAnimClass="slideTextFromBottom";
    }

    if(n!=slideIndex){
        next = slides[n];
        current=slides[slideIndex];
        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
            slides[i].className = "imageHolder";
            slides[i].style.opacity=0;
            dots[i].classList.remove("active");
        }
        current.classList.add(moveSlideAnimClass.forCurrent);
        next.classList.add(moveSlideAnimClass.forNext);
        dots[n].classList.add("active");
        slideIndex=n;
        captionText.style.display="none";
        captionText.className="captionText "+slideTextAnimClass;
        captionText.innerText=slides[n].querySelector(".captionText").innerText;
        captionText.style.display="block";
    }

}

var timer=null;
function setTimer(){
    timer=setInterval(function () {
        plusSlides(1) ;
    },3000);
}
setTimer();
function playPauseSlides() {
    var playPauseBtn=document.getElementById("playPause");
    if(timer==null){
        setTimer();
        playPauseBtn.style.backgroundPositionY="0px"
    }else{
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer=null;
        playPauseBtn.style.backgroundPositionY="-33px"
    }
}
```

```css
body {
    /*background-image: url(../images/ilhas.jpg);*/
    background-color: #3f4043;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    /*max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;*/ 
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; 
    margin:0;
}

/*TITULO*/


#barNav {
    
    margin-top: 3%;
    width:100%;
    
}

header{
    background-image: url(../images/banner1.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 20%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: auto;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: left;
}

header .logo{
    float: left;
    width: 3.5%;
    min-width: 40px;
    margin-top: 0.2%;
    margin-left: 28%;
    margin-right: 2%;
}

#tituloPrincipal {
    color: lightgray;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#tituloAzores {
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    background: lightblue;
    color: black;
    font-size: 30px;
}

#tituloSantaMaria {
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    background: rgba(223, 201, 11, 0.952);
    color: black;
    font-size: 30px;
}

ul {
    margin-left: 1.2%;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    font-family: arial;
    
}
   
ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 11%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: .8;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}
   
ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    display: block;
}

/* CORES BARRA NAV PARA CADA ILHA */ 
#ilhaSantaMaria { 
    background:#efef32; 
    color:#3f4043; 
} 
#ilhaSantaMaria a:hover {
    background:#e4d637;
    color: #3f4043;
}

#ilhaSaoMiguel { 
    background:#4cd33d; 
    color:#fff; 
} 
#ilhaSaoMiguel a:hover {
    background:#3fbf34; 
    color:#fff;
}

#ilhaTerceira { 
    background:#c66ca0; 
    color:#fff; 
} 
#ilhaTerceira a:hover {
    background:#ad5788; 
    color:#fff;
}

#ilhaGraciosa { 
    background:#fbfbfb; 
    color:#333; 
} 
#ilhaGraciosa a:hover {
    background:#dadada; 
    color:#333;
}

#ilhaSaoJorge { 
    background:#f4949b; 
    color:#fff; 
} 
#ilhaSaoJorge a:hover {
    background:#d6878d; 
    color:#fff;
}

#ilhaPico {
    background:#7c837a; 
    color:#fff; 
}
#ilhaPico a:hover {
    background:#666c64; 
    color:#fff;
}

#ilhaFaial {
    background:#317eb2; 
    color:#fff; 
}
#ilhaFaial a:hover {
    background:#296a95; 
    color:#fff;
}

#ilhaFlores {
    background:#84e275; 
    color:#fff; 
}
#ilhaFlores a:hover {
    background:#74cc67; 
    color:#fff;
}

#ilhaCorvo {
    background:#7a6148; 
    color:#fff; 
}
#ilhaCorvo a:hover {
    background:#654f39; 
    color:#fff;
}

/*  FIM CORES BARRA NAV PARA CADA ILHA */ 

ul li ul li{
    display: none;
}

ul li:hover ul li {
    display: block;
    width:100%;
}

/*      SLIDESHOW       */ 
html,body{
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.galleryContainer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
    user-select: none;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 1px #00000078;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.galleryContainer .slideShowContainer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: gainsboro;
    position: relative;
}
.galleryContainer .slideShowContainer #playPause{
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url("../icons/playPause.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: 5;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.galleryContainer .slideShowContainer #playPause:hover{
    opacity: .7;
}
.galleryContainer .slideShowContainer .imageHolder{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
}
.galleryContainer .slideShowContainer .imageHolder img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.galleryContainer .slideShowContainer .imageHolder .captionText{
    display: none;
}

.galleryContainer .slideShowContainer .leftArrow,.galleryContainer .slideShowContainer .rightArrow{
    width: 50px;
    background: #00000036;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: background 0.5s;
    height: 72px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
.galleryContainer .slideShowContainer .rightArrow{
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
.galleryContainer .slideShowContainer .leftArrow:hover,.galleryContainer .slideShowContainer .rightArrow:hover{
    background: #000000a8;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.galleryContainer .arrow{
    display: inline-block;
    border: 3px solid white;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-left: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.galleryContainer .arrow.arrowLeft{
    transform: rotateZ(-135deg);
}
.galleryContainer .arrow.arrowRight{
    transform: rotateZ(45deg);
}


.galleryContainer .slideShowContainer>.captionTextHolder {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    background: none;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.galleryContainer .slideShowContainer>.captionTextHolder>.captionText{
    margin: 0;
}

.galleryContainer #dotsContainer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.galleryContainer #dotsContainer .dots{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 5px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition:background-color 0.5s;
}
.galleryContainer #dotsContainer .dots:first-child{
    margin-left: 0;
}
.galleryContainer #dotsContainer .dots:hover,.galleryContainer #dotsContainer .dots.active{
    background-color: #717171;;
}

.galleryContainer .moveLeftCurrentSlide{
    animation-name: moveLeftCurrent;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;

}
.galleryContainer .moveLeftNextSlide{
    animation-name: moveLeftNext;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}
@keyframes moveLeftCurrent {
    from {margin-left: 0;opacity: 1;}
    to {margin-left: -100%;opacity: 1;}
}
@keyframes moveLeftNext {
    from {margin-left: 100%;opacity: 1;}
    to {margin-left: 0%;opacity: 1;}
}


.galleryContainer .moveRightCurrentSlide{
    animation-name: moveRightCurrent;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}
.galleryContainer .moveRightPrevSlide{
    animation-name: moveRightPrev;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}
@keyframes moveRightCurrent {
    from {margin-left: 0;opacity: 1;}
    to {margin-left: 100%;opacity: 1;}
}
@keyframes moveRightPrev {
    from {margin-left: -100%;opacity: 1;}
    to {margin-left: 0%;opacity: 1;}
}
.slideTextFromBottom {
    animation-name: slideTextFromBottom;
    animation-duration: 0.7s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
}
@keyframes slideTextFromBottom {
    from {opacity: 0;margin-top: 100px}
    to {opacity: 1;margin-top: 0px;}
}
.slideTextFromTop {
    animation-name: slideTextFromTop;
    animation-duration: 0.7s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
}
@keyframes slideTextFromTop {
    from {opacity: 0;margin-top: -100px}
    to {opacity: 1;margin-top: 0px;}
}

/*      FIM SLIDESHOW        */


/*Toogle */ 

#botaoUpDown {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 50px 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: orange;
    margin-top: 20px;
}


/*Fim Toogle */ 


/*Paginas com click drop*/
.h2_drop {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.click_and_drop {
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
}

.click_and_drop li {
    list-style: none;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 5vmin;
    border-top: solid rgb(189, 189, 189);
    margin-left: -4.1%;
    display: block;
}

.elementoLista {
    padding: 1%;
    overflow: auto;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

.title {
    float: left;
}

.seta {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 0%;
}

.pEscondido {
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 1%;
    width: 50%
}

.mapaEscondido {
    float: right;
    width: 400px;
    height: 350px;
    border: 0;
}

.esconde {
    font-size: 3vmin;
    display: none;
    overflow: auto;
}

h5 {
    font-size: 4vmin;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    margin-bottom: -3%;
    margin-top: 0%;
}

.estrelas {
    margin-left: 5%;
}
/*FIM Paginas click drop*/



/*FOOTER*/
footer {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.74);
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    bottom: 0;
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
}

/*FIM FOOTER*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="author" content="João Lopes, Wilson Lima, Cristina Santos">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8" lang="pt">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" initial-scale="1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="O que conhecer e fazer no arquipelago dos Açores">
        <meta name="keywords" content="Açores, Gastronomia, Transportes..."> <!--TODO-->

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/styles.css">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/jpeg" href="icons/azoresIcon.jpeg"/>

        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

        
        <title>Ilha de Santa Maria</title>

    </head>

    <body onload="time()">  

        <main id="topo">
        
            <header>
                <a href="index.html"><img src="icons/azoresIcon.png" class="logo"/><h1 id="tituloPrincipal">Santa Maria</h1></a>
            </header>
            <br><br><br><br><br>
 
            <!--BARRA NAVEGAÇÃO-->
    <div id="barNav">
        <ul>
            <li id="ilhaSantaMaria"><a  href="ilhaSantaMaria.html">Santa Maria</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="ilhaSantaMaria.html">Alojamento</a></li>
                    <li><a href="ilhaSantaMaria.html">Gastronomia</a></li>
                    <li><a href="ilhaSantaMaria.html">Transportes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="ilhaSantaMaria.html">Animação</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            
            <li id="ilhaSaoMiguel"><a  href="ilhaSaoMiguel.html">São Miguel</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="ilhaSantaMaria.html">Alojamento</a></li>
                    <li><a href="ilhaSantaMaria.html">Gastronomia</a></li>
                    <li><a href="ilhaSantaMaria.html">Transportes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="ilhaSantaMaria.html">Animação</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li id="ilhaTerceira"><a  href="ilhaTerceira.html">Terceira</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="ilhaSantaMaria.html">Alojamento</a></li>
                    <li><a href="ilhaSantaMaria.html">Gastronomia</a></li>
                    <li><a href="ilhaSantaMaria.html">Transportes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="ilhaSantaMaria.html">Animação</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li id="ilhaGraciosa"><a  href="ilhaGraciosa.html">Graciosa</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="ilhaSantaMaria.html">Alojamento</a></li>
                    <li><a href="ilhaSantaMaria.html">Gastronomia</a></li>
                    <li><a href="ilhaSantaMaria.html">Transportes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="ilhaSantaMaria.html">Animação</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li id="ilhaSaoJorge"><a  href="ilhaSaoJorge.html">São Jorge</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="ilhaSantaMaria.html">Alojamento</a></li>
                    <li><a href="ilhaSantaMaria.html">Gastronomia</a></li>
                    <li><a href="ilhaSantaMaria.html">Transportes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="ilhaSantaMaria.html">Animação</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li id="ilhaPico"><a  href="ilhaPico.html">Pico</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="ilhaSantaMaria.html">Alojamento</a></li>
                    <li><a href="ilhaSantaMaria.html">Gastronomia</a></li>
                    <li><a href="ilhaSantaMaria.html">Transportes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="ilhaSantaMaria.html">Animação</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li id="ilhaFaial"><a  href="ilhaFaial.html">Faial</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="ilhaSantaMaria.html">Alojamento</a></li>
                    <li><a href="ilhaSantaMaria.html">Gastronomia</a></li>
                    <li><a href="ilhaSantaMaria.html">Transportes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="ilhaSantaMaria.html">Animação</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li id="ilhaFlores"><a  href="ilhaFlores.html">Flores</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="ilhaSantaMaria.html">Alojamento</a></li>
                    <li><a href="ilhaSantaMaria.html">Gastronomia</a></li>
                    <li><a href="ilhaSantaMaria.html">Transportes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="ilhaSantaMaria.html">Animação</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li id="ilhaCorvo"><a  href="ilhaCorvo.html">Corvo</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="ilhaSantaMaria.html">Alojamento</a></li>
                    <li><a href="ilhaSantaMaria.html">Gastronomia</a></li>
                    <li><a href="ilhaSantaMaria.html">Transportes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="ilhaSantaMaria.html">Animação</a></li>
                </ul>
        </ul>
    </div>
                    <!--FIM BARRA NAVEGAÇÃO-->



        <!--SLIDESHOW-->
        <div class="galleryContainer">
            <div class="slideShowContainer">
                <div id="playPause" onclick="playPauseSlides()"></div>
                <div onclick="plusSlides(-1)" class="nextPrevBtn leftArrow"><span class="arrow arrowLeft"></span></div>
                <div onclick="plusSlides(1)" class="nextPrevBtn rightArrow"><span class="arrow arrowRight"></span></div>
                <div class="captionTextHolder"><p class="captionText slideTextFromTop"></p></div>
                <div class="imageHolder">
                    <img src="images/smaria1.jpg">1366X768
                    <p class="captionText"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="imageHolder">
                    <img src="images/smaria2.jpg">
                    <p class="captionText"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="imageHolder">
                    <img src="images/smaria3.jpg">
                    <p class="captionText"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="dotsContainer"></div>
        </div>

        <!--FIM SLIDESHOW-->

        <!--TOOGLE-->

        <button id="botaoUpDown" onclick="toggle('alojamento')">ALOJAMENTO</button>

        <div id="alojamento">
        ALOJAMENTO
        </div>
        <br>

        <button id="botaoUpDown" onclick="toggle('gastronomia')">GASTRONOMIA</button id="botaoUpDown">
        <div id="gastronomia">
        GASTRONOMIA
        </div>
        <br>

        <button id="botaoUpDown" onclick="toggle('transporte')">TRASNPORTE</button id="botaoUpDown">
        <div id="transporte">
            TRASNPORTE
        </div>
        <br>

        <button id="botaoUpDown" onclick="toggle('animacao')">ANIMAÇÃO</button>
        <div id="animacao">
        ANIMAÇÃO
        </div>
        <br>


<!--

        <button id="botaoUpDown" onclick="toogle()">ALOJAMENTO</button>

        <div class="gaveta">
            Pousada de Viseu
            <br>
            Rua do Hospital
            <br>
            3500-161 Viseu
            <br> 
            Portugal
            <br>
            <br>
            Email: guest@pousadas.pt
            <br>
            Telefone:(+351) 232 457 320
            <br>
            Fax: (+351) 232 421 128
            <br>
            <br>
            Website: <a href="http://www.pousadadeviseu.com">www.pousadadeviseu.com</a>
        </p>
        </div>

        <button id="botaoUpDown" onclick="toogle()">GASTRONOMIA</button>

        <div class="gaveta">
            Pousada de Viseu
            <br>
            Rua do Hospital
            <br>
            3500-161 Viseu
            <br> 
            Portugal
            <br>
            <br>
            Email: guest@pousadas.pt
            <br>
            Telefone:(+351) 232 457 320
            <br>
            Fax: (+351) 232 421 128
            <br>
            <br>
            Website: <a href="http://www.pousadadeviseu.com">www.pousadadeviseu.com</a>
        </div>

        -->
        
        <footer>
            <br><br>
            contactos
            <a id="tempoActual" style="float: right; font-size: 1.6vmin; line-height: 0; margin-top: -1%; margin-right: 2%;"></a>
        </footer>
        
        </main>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/javascript.js"></script>  
    </body>
</html>
```

.

Comment: try to give z-index to dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `position: relative;` and `z-index: 11` to `ul`.

```
ul {
    margin-left: 1.2%;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    font-family: arial;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 11;
}
```

I hope this will works for you.

Thank you...

Comment: You're an wizard! Thanks alot!!

Comment: if this works for you then make this ans right by clicking the right symbol at the left side of my answer.

Comment: it doesnt let me to thumbs up because i have low reputation

Answer (score 0):

Add this code ul li{position:relative; z-index: 1}